# Why are lambda expressions used in after_filter on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I inherited this code but can't get my head around this part:

I have the following controller:

```
class MenuCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  after_filter lambda { |controller| controller.update_other_locals_for(@menu_category) }, :only => [:create, :update]

  # GET /menu_categories
  # GET /menu_categories.json
  def index
...
```

In the application_controller is this:

```
def update_other_locals_for(item)
    available_locals = item.menu.shop.chosen_locals
...
```

Normally update_other_locals_for should be hit when an item is updated or created.  I set a breakpoint and this never seems to happen.  Does this need a lambda expression?  What could be the reason why it's not hit after creation or update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something in Rails isn't happening like you think it should in a controller, remember to check that:

- you routes are properly defined
- your abilities are correct

To start with you can check that you hit breakpoints set in the create and update actions for MenuCategoriesController.   If your actions are not being called, then of course you won't see the after_filter.

If you suspect the lambda, try replacing it with a method and verify that the method gets called.